# How to match existing elements in queue and add the non-existing ones into a different queue?

Tags: queue, verilog, system-verilog

I have a question regarding the queues in SystemVerilog.

Example: How do I compare the strings in `Q[$]` with `q1[$]` and `q2[$]` and put them in `q3[$]` using `foreach`?

```
string Q[$]  = {"mango","apple","banana","kiwi","berries","melons","papaya"};
string q1[$] = {"mango","apple"};
string q2[$] = {"kiwi","berries","melons"};
string q3[$] = {};
```

```
foreach(Q\[i\])
begin
foreach(q1\[j\])
begin
foreach(q2\[k\])
begin
if(Q\[i\].get_name() != (q1\[j\] | q2 \[k\]))
begin
q3.push_front(Q\[i\]);
end
end
end
end
```

Comment: But the comparision  is getting done multiple times , I only need once for q3

Comment: @Dig_Verif_bee, It would help if you show what final results you are looking for in q3, and if duplicate names are allowed in Q, q1, and q2. And what is get_name() supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to add the elements from `Q` which are not in either `q1` or `q2` to `q3`:

```
module tb;

string Q[$]  = {"mango","apple","banana","kiwi","berries","melons","papaya"};
string q1[$] = {"mango","apple"};
string q2[$] = {"kiwi","berries","melons"};
string q3[$] = {};

initial begin
    foreach (Q[i]) begin
        string qi [$];

        qi = q1.find_first() with (item == Q[i]);
        if (qi.size()) continue;

        qi = q2.find_first() with (item == Q[i]);
        if (qi.size()) continue;

        q3.push_back(Q[i]);
    end
    $display("q3 %p", q3);
end

endmodule
```

Output:

```
q3 '{"banana", "papaya"}
```

It loops through all elements of `Q`.  If the element is not found in `q1` and the element is not found in `q2`, then add the element to `q3`.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 7.12.1 *Array locator methods*.